# how to make confirm password validation cakephp with hashing it

Tags: php, validation, cakephp, hash, sha256

I'm using cakephp 2.xx, I want to hashing password with sha256 before it going to database,
before it I wanna make validation value password in my form input, validation which check password input and re-confirm password is match, if In my controller, when form catch validation, the password automatically hash

```
if ($this->request->data['Driver']['password'] != $this->request->data['Driver']['confirm_password']) {
      $this->request->data['Driver']['password'] = hash('sha256',$this->request->data['Driver']['password']);
}
```

necessarily, the password hash when form no catch validate at all, so how can I make validation in my model ?

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your model (Driver.php)

Validation

```
<?php 
    public $validate = array(

        'password' => array(
            'notempty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notempty'),                            
            ),
            'password_confirm'=>array(
                'rule'=>array('password_confirm'),
                'message'=>'Password Confirmation must match Password',                         
            ),    
        ),      
    );
?>
```

Custom validation rule

```
<?php 
    public function password_confirm(){ 
        if ($this->data['Driver']['password'] !== $this->data['Driver']['password_confirmation']){
            return false;       
        }
        return true;
    }
?>
```

Hashing,but I think that better to choose AuthComponent

```
<?php 
    public function beforeSave($options = array()) {        
        $this->data['Driver']['password'] = hash('sha256',$this->data['Driver']['password']);   
        return true;        
    }
?>
```

It's overall description and you probably would need to modify some parts of it